# expected identifier before string constant

Tags: c++, linux, constructor

Having a program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class test
{
public:
    test(std::string s):str(s){};
private:
    std::string str;
};

class test1
{
public:
    test tst_("Hi");
};

int main()
{
    return 1;
}
```

…why am I getting the following when I execute

> g++ main.cpp

```
main.cpp:16:12: error: expected identifier before string constant
main.cpp:16:12: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant
```

Comment: You really should learn to always compile with `g++ -Wall -g`

Comment: `-Wall`: *"Enable most warning messages."* and `-g`: *"Generate debug information in default format."* or *"generate debugging information"* -- source: `g++ -v --help`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can not initialize `tst_` where you declare it. This can only be done for `static const` primitive types. Instead you will need to have a constructor for `class test1`.

EDIT: below, you will see a working example I did in [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/y4h52). Note a few changes I did. First, it is better to have the constructor of `test` take a `const` reference to `string` to avoid copying. Second, if the program succeeds you should `return 0` not `1` (with `return 1` you get a runtime error in [ideone](http://ideone.com/h8n2V)).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class test
{
public:
    test(const std::string& s):str(s){};
private:
    std::string str;
};
 
class test1
{
public:
    test1() : tst_("Hi") {}
    test tst_;
};
 
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"You can not initialize `tst_` where you declare it. This can only be done for `static const` primitive types."* -- out of curiosity, "why not?" I mean what could possibly go wrong if it was possible to initialize `tst_` where it was declared? Is it to avoid some possible bad behavior? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I can't give an exact reason for that as I am not the creator of the language. I don't think something bad would happen but probably the implementation (of the language) was easier this way

Answer (score 1):

There is another and more simplified way of doing what you want:Just change your statement from `test tst_("Hi");` to `test tst_{"Hi"};` and it will work. Below is the modified code and it works as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class test
{
public:
    test(std::string s):str(s){cout<<"str is: "<<s;}
private:
    std::string str;
};

class test1
{
public:
    test tst_{"Hi"};
};

int main()
{   test1 obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that i have just changed `test tst_("Hi");` to `test tst_{"Hi"};` and everything else is exactly the same. Just for confirmation that this works i have added one cout to check that it initialize the str variable correctly. I think this one line solution is more elegant(at least to me) and and up to date with the new standard.

Comment: Why exactly `test tst_{"Hi"}` works but `test tst_("Hi")` does not? Could you please elaborate? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @Milan Sure. The problem is that in C++11 when using in-class initializers we can use `{}` but not `()`. The same is explained here in more detail: [Why C++11 in-class initializer cannot use parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836526/why-c11-in-class-initializer-cannot-use-parentheses). Note also that you can find many other SO posts explaining the same.