# In-class member initializer using a constructor: is it allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, in-class-initialization

I recently found an interesting piece of code in the article [*Get to Know the New C++11 Initialization Forms*](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519) by Danny Kalev:

```
class C
{
string s("abc");
double d=0;
char * p {nullptr};
int y[5] {1,2,3,4};
public:
C();
};
```

The line `string s("abc");` seems suspicious to me. I thought that using a constructor is not allowed while a member is initialized in-class.
And this code (simplified to `class C { string s("abc");` };`) doesn't compile with

- [*clang 3.6.1*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/691b80d678b72d1f) (compiler arguments are `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`)
- [*g++ 5.1.0*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff0c30d1e4560cc6) (compiler arguments are the same: `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`)
- [*vc++ 18.00.21005.1*](http://rextester.com/JBVXY34880) (compiler arguments are `/EHsc /Wall /wd4514 /wd4710 /wd4820 /WX /Za`)
- [*vc++ 19.00.22929.0*](http://rise4fun.com/vcpp) (compiler arguments are predefined by the service: `/EHsc /nologo /W4 /c`)

Am I right and there is an error in this article?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I right and there is an error in this article?

Yes, it is an error in the article.

Only a *brace-or-equal-initializer* is allowed in the declaration of a data member. The initializations of `d`, `p`, and `y` are correct, but not `s`. The rationale for this is that using an *expression-list* would ambiguate the declaration with a function declaration and it would also cause conflicts with name lookup in the class body.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a reference to the standard? I think that you pointed out the true rationale for this behavior.

Comment: @Constructor The standard doesn't explicitly give a rationale. The rule is simply found in [class.mem]/p4. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24837330/701092

Comment: Do you mean [class.mem]/p5? And thank you very much for this reference! It is very good.

Comment: @Constructor I'm using the latest draft, n4431. You're probably using n3242.

Comment: Oh, yes. n3337, to be precise.

Comment: I usually use nearest to C++11 standard drafts to check pure C++11 features.

Answer (score 1):

[An example from Bjarne Stroustrup:](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init)

```
class A {
    public:
        A() {}
        A(int a_val) : a(a_val) {}
        A(D d) : b(g(d)) {}
        int a = 7;
        int b = 5;  
    private:
        HashingFunction hash_algorithm{"MD5"};  // Cryptographic hash to be applied to all A instances
        std::string s{"Constructor run"};       // String indicating state in object lifecycle
    };
```