# C++ says expected identifier before numeric constant

Tags: c++

```
class data
{
private:
    int ID;
    string address,name;
public:
    data(int i,string a,string n):ID(i),address(a),name(n){}
    friend class SetData;
};
class SetData
{
private:
    data obj(43,"185 Awan Market","Talha"); //this is where the error happens

public:
    void show()
    {
        cout<<"Name is: "<<obj.name<<endl;
        cout<<"Address is: "<<obj.address<<endl;
        cout<<"ID is: "<<obj.ID;
    }
};
```

Comment: NSDMI supports only brace-or-equal initializers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**C++03**

It belongs in the constructor's mem-initializer:

```
class SetData
{
private:
    data obj;

public:
    SetData() : obj(43,"185 Awan Market","Talha")
    {
    }
    // Rest goes here...
};
```

**C++11**

You must use a brace ***or*** equal initializer.

```
// Fine
data obj{43,"185 Awan Market","Talha"};
// Fine, too
data obj = data(43,"185 Awan Market","Talha"); //this is where the error happens
```

For why parentheses are not allowed, see the [Non-static data member initializers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm) proposal. Scroll down to "An issue raised in Kona regarding scope of identifiers"

> The motivation for class-scope lookup is that we’d like to be able to
>   put anything in a non-static data member’s initializer that we could
>   put in a mem-initializer without significantly changing the semantics
>   (modulo direct initialization vs. copy initialization):
>
> ```
> int x();
>
> struct S {
>     int i;
>     S() : i(x()) {} // currently well-formed, uses S::x()
>     // ...
>     static int x();
> };
>
> struct T {
>     int i = x(); // should use T::x(), ::x() would be a surprise
>     // ...
>     static int x();
> };
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, this makes initializers of the “( expression-list )”
>   form ambiguous at the time that the declaration is being parsed:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>     int i(x); // data member with initializer
>     // ...
>     static int x;
> };
>
> struct T {
>     int i(x); // member function declaration
>     // ...
>     typedef int x;
> };
> ```
>
> One possible solution is to rely on the existing rule that, if a
>   declaration could be an object or a function, then it’s a function:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>     int i(j); // ill-formed...parsed as a member function,
>               // type j looked up but not found
>     // ...
>     static int j;
> };
> ```
>
> A similar solution would be to apply another existing rule, currently
>   used only in templates, that if T could be a type or something else,
>   then it’s something else; and we can use “typename” if we really mean
>   a type: Essentially
>
> ```
> struct S {
>     int i(x); // unabmiguously a data member
>     int j(typename y); // unabmiguously a member function
> };
> ```
>
> Both of those solutions introduce subtleties that are likely to be
>   misunderstood by many users (as evidenced by the many questions on
>   comp.lang.c++ about why “int i();” at block scope doesn’t declare a
>   default-initialized int).
>
> The solution proposed in this paper is to allow only initializers of
>   the “= initializer-clause” and “{ initializer-list }” forms. That
>   solves the ambiguity problem in most cases, for example:
>
> ```
> HashingFunction hash_algorithm{"MD5"};
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Initializing non-static data members in such a way is not allowed. You should rather be using a brace-or-equal initializer

```
class SetData
{
private:
    // data obj = {43,"185 Awan Market","Talha"}; is also valid
    data obj{43,"185 Awan Market","Talha"};
```

Cfr. [non-static data members initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

Alternative solution: constructor initializer list

```
class SetData
{
private:
    data obj;

public:
    SetData() : obj(43,"185 Awan Market","Talha") {}

    void show() 
    ...
};
```

As to why parenthesis are not supported for non-static data members initialization, I recommend reading this post: [Why C++11 in-class initializer cannot use parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836526/why-c11-in-class-initializer-cannot-use-parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize objects *inline* like that, you have to do it in the constructors initializer list:

```
class SetData
{
private:
    data obj;

public:
    SetData() : obj(43,"185 Awan Market","Talha") {}
    ...
};
```