# Nested Class. error: expected parameter declarator - for inner class instance

Tags: c++, c++11, member-initialization

I started learning about nested classes in C++, I tried a quick code which I pasted here to see how nested classes work. But the compilation end with some errors which I can't figure out.

**File: check.cpp**

```
class Outside{
    public:
        class Inside{
            private:
                int mInside;
            public:
                Inside(const int& x):mInside(x){}
        };
    private:
        Inside mOutside(20);
};

int main(void){
Outside o;
return 0;
}
```

The error which I get on compiling by `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o check.out check.cpp`

```
check.cpp:12:25: error: expected parameter declarator
        Inside mOutside(20);
                        ^
check.cpp:12:25: error: expected ')'
check.cpp:12:24: note: to match this '('
        Inside mOutside(20);
                       ^
```

I need a good explanation behind this error and how to overcome this error.

Comment: duplicate of [Why C++11 in-class initializer cannot use parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24836526/3953764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `=` or `{}` for in-place member initialization:

```
// ...
private:
    Inside mOutside = 20;
```

The parentheses form would be ambiguous (it could be [confused with a function declaration](http://%20%20public:%20%20%20%20%20Inside(const%20int&%20x):mInside(x)%7B%7D)).

---

```
Inside mOutside{20};
```

With `clang++` this triggers the warning:

> warning: private field 'mInside' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]

and the compiler has a point. The strange thing is the missing warning with the other form (`=`).

Answer (score 1):

Try using this way of member initializing.

```
Inside mOutside = Inside(20);
```

> Yes, your solution worked thank you. But how? Why?

See [Initializing bases and members in open-std](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf#page=269).

Comment: @jblixr NSDMI requires a brace-or-equal initializer syntax