# How to init constructor parameters of a member in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I have the following code (header file):

```
class InnerClass
{
    InnerClass(int var);
}

class BigClass
{
    BigClass();
    InnerClass member(5);
}
```

How can I initialize the parameter of member in BigClass to 5 (the above code generates an error, as you probably guessed)? If I put the InnerClass member(5) line in the code (not header) file, then no problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why C++11 in-class initializer cannot use parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836526/why-c11-in-class-initializer-cannot-use-parentheses)

Comment: Yes @cpplearner, part of this link answers my question. But I believe my question (and the accepted answer) is more direct to the point. Also the accepted answer clearly shows the difference with C++11 syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could initialize the member variable `BigClass::member` by [in-class brace-or-equal initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since c++11):

```
InnerClass member{5};
```

or [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class BigClass
{
    InnerClass member;
public:
    BigClass() : member(5) {}
    // or... BigClass(int var) : member(var) {}
}
```

<sup>BTW: I suppose the constructor of `InnerClass` should be public.</sup>