# Why we cannot do data member initialization inside class with parenthesis?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

I could not understand why c++11 allows braced initialization,assignment but not initialization with parenthesis for data members inside class. Below is code snippet for more clarity:

```
class Person {
private:
    string name="Kapil"; //this is allowed
    string organization{"Test"};//even this works
    string place("Rest"); //this is not working what's wrong?
public:

};
```

So specifically i am looking for what is reasoning for not allowing parenthesis initialization of data members?

Comment: Needless complexity. Why do you want yet another way to do the same thing?

Comment: Also, ambiguity: Currently, `int f(int(a))` already means something.

Comment: Another dup: [Why C++11 in-class initializer cannot use parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836526/why-c11-in-class-initializer-cannot-use-parentheses)