# Instance variable initialization in C++ private area

Tags: c++, object, constructor

In class A,`counter b(5);` doesn't work.

while `counter a;` (the call of the default constructor) works.

Why? Is it not possible to call a parameterized constructor for an instance variable?

```
class counter {
private:
  int value;
public:
  counter() { this->value = 0; }
  counter(int value) { this->value = value; }
};

class A {
  private:
    // works
    counter a;
    // works (since C++11)
    int x = 5; 
    // doesn't work
    counter b(5);
};

int main()
{
// works
counter myCounter;
// works as well
counter mySecondCounter(5);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `this->`. And your argument and member have the same name. Rename it to something like `v` or `value_`.

Comment: Also, use an inizialisation list: `counter() : value(0) {}` and `counter(int v) : value(v) {}`. Or even use a default argument, then you have only one constructor. This is more expressive: your counter normally starts at 0, except if you explicitly want to start it from somewhere else. Further, make it capital: `Counter`.

Comment: Inside a class definition, `some_type some_name(` makes the compiler expect a member function declaration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why C++11 in-class initializer cannot use parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836526/why-c11-in-class-initializer-cannot-use-parentheses)

Comment: @SauravSahu same answer, different question

Answer (score 3):

*If allowed*, `counter b(5);` technically declares a function named `b` that returns a `counter` object by value, and takes a single argument that's an integer.

While that, very likely, would not be the intention of the coder, that's why it is not allowed.

**In Bjarne's words about this rule for *In-Class Initializers*:**

We can specify an initializer for a non-static data member in the class declaration. For example:

```
class A {
  public:
    int a {7};
    int b = 77;
};
```

For pretty obscure technical reasons related to parsing and name lookup, the `{}` and `=` initializer
    notations can be used for in-class member initializers, but **the `()` notation cannot.**

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Change

```
counter b(5);
```

to

```
counter b = counter(5);
```

It is perhaps more elegant to initialise in a constructor intialisation list.

```
class A {
private:
    A() : b(5) {}

    counter a;
    int x = 5;
    counter b;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have four options:

```
class A {
private:
    counter C1{5};

    // Works, only with single parameter constructors
    counter C2 = 5;

    // Works, with any number of parameters
    counter C3 = counter(5);

    counter C4;

    // Constructor initializer list, works with any number of parameters
    A() : C4(5) {}
};
```

Comment: This will be great answer if you can answer the main question why `counter b(5);` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, this is not the correct syntax for initializing members with default values.

There are two options to solve it:

1.use operator =

```
counter b = counter(5);
```

2.use constructor with initialization list

```
A() : a(),b(5) {}
```