# Pointer Initialization for Class vs Non-Class Variables

Tags: c++

I wouldn't be surprised if this has been discussed before, but I've no idea what the magic search terms are to find the answer.

Why does this compile,

```
int main() {
  int* p(new int());
  return 0;
}
```

while this doesn't,

```
class X {
  int* p(new int());
};
```

yet this does?

```
class X {
  int* p = new int();
};
```

Comment: "downvotes" - there's a single downvote..

Answer (score 1):

This is a most vexing parse.

In the second case, I believe `p` is being parsed as a function (but I'm not sure).  Regardless, it's not being parsed as a pointer to an `int` initialized with the value `new int()`.  Replacing the parentheses with curly braces fixes the issue.

Although I have found the source of the issue, I would be grateful if someone could tell me how exactly the parser is interpreting the second example in the question.  I still don't fully understand what is happening.

Comment: I don't think "most vexing parse" applies here. The same tokens `int *p(new int());` are fine inside a function block and declare a pointer object, not a function, since there's no way `new int()` could be a parameter list.

Comment: That's why I was so confused.  I may definitely be wrong to call it a most vexing parse, but it is a very vexing parse nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

The "in-class" initialization that you are trying to use is a C++11 feature that requires either `=` or `{}` initializer syntax

```
class X {
  int* p = new int();
};
```

or

```
class X {
  int* p{ new int() };
};
```

Firstly, C++11 places extra emphasis of the *uniform initialization* syntax, based around `{}` initializers. Secondly, `()` syntax in this context would potentially create unnecessary ambiguities with class member function declaration syntax.

Comment: I do wonder if a paper behind the language addition mentions if the reason for not allowing parentheses-style initializers was specifically to avoid an analogue of the Most Vexing Parse.

Comment: My problem with uniform initialization syntax is that I'm constantly using vectors which interpret curly braces differently...

Comment: @aschepler: Answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24837330/187690 - says that this is related to ambiguous parsing, but it is more of a *lookup* ambiguity, not a pure Most Vexing Parse ambiguity.