# Declaring a variable size array/vector inside a C++ class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop

I want to declare a variable size (not really variable size) array/vector inside a C++ class and I am encountering weird errors. I have tried to find a solution to this but cannot resolve the error.
C++ gods, bless me.

```
class threeStack{
    private:
        int numberOfStacks = 3;
        int sizeOfEachStack = 2;
        int kc = 10;
        vector <int> a(numberOfStacks * sizeOfEachStack);
        vector <int> tops(numberOfStacks);
        };
```

**ERRORS**

```
         vector <int> a(numberOfStacks * sizeOfEachStack);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:27: error: ‘numberOfStacks’ is not a type
         vector <int> tops(numberOfStacks);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: dont include the code that we need not read. See [mcve]

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - alright, got it

Comment: Why do you think you can do `vector<int> a(n);`? Which [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) says you can?

Comment: @Evg if I have defined n before `vector <int> a(n);`, I can definitely use that.

Comment: @Anant Inside a function body, not inside a class definition. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836526/why-c11-in-class-initializer-cannot-use-parentheses).

Comment: @Evg gotcha, arigato.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2824f8cf7a4ff0c6

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify constructor arguments to class members when they are declared.  That's done in the contructor of the class itself.

```
class threeStack{
    private:
        int numberOfStacks;
        int sizeOfEachStack;
        int kc;
        vector <int> a;
        vector <int> tops;

    public:
        threeStack() : numberOfStacks(3), sizeOfEachStack(2), 
                       kc(10), a(3 * 2), tops(3) {
        }

        threeStack(int numberOfStacks, int sizeOfEachStack) : 
            numberOfStacks(numberOfStacks),
            sizeOfEachStack(sizeOfEachStack),
            kc(10), 
            a(numberOfStacks * sizeOfEachStack), 
            tops(sizeOfEachStack) 
        {
        }
};
```

Also, default initialization of data members is a feature of C++11 and later, so if you're compiling with an older version of the standard you'll need to specify those in the constructor as well.

Comment: "You don't specify constructor arguments to class members when they are declared, nor can you specify default values." Of course you can. It is called default member initializer

Answer (score 0):

This is declaration of a function:

```
vector <int> tops(numberOfStacks);
|            |   ||
|            |   |type of first parameter
|            |   parameter list
|            name of the function
return type
```

You cannot use this syntax for default member initialiser.

Comment: can you recommend me something which I can read to learn this stuff? atleast the basics, I am currently reading "accelerated c++" though.

Comment: @Anant There's a list of books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). I cannot vouch for any particular book myself. My only C++ book is some old edition of Bjarne's The C++ Programming Language.

Comment: "Also, you cannot refer to other members in a default member initialiser." I think you can? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2824f8cf7a4ff0c6

Comment: @phön I guess I just assumed that ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @eerorika ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯