# Calling a constructor of a class member

Tags: c++

What I want to use has no default constructor - so in my class definition, I need to call a parameterized constructor inside that class.

My question is - how?

```
class ServerSocket
{
public:
    ....

private:
    ....
    asio::io_context io_context;
    tcp::socket socket(io_context); //the compiler will think this is a function definition - 
                    //but it isn't, I want to instantiate an object of type tcp::socket
                    //with io_context as a parameter

    ServerSocket()
    {
        //I thought about moving tcp::socket here, but then I won't have access to the socket accross the class
    }
};
```

Comment: `tcp::socket socket{io_context}`? Related: [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222926/11082165)

Comment: Is it your intention to make `ServerSocket`'s constructor `private`?

Comment: @DrewDormann yes, in this case my ServerSocket is a singleton :) but I didn't go into details because it is not related to my question

Comment: You don't need to have both the **declaration** of the `socket` class member and the **assignment** in the same place. `tcp::socket* socket;` can be declared in the class and allows you to construct the instance later.

Comment: @Brian yes - it worked - I didn't know about that.

Comment: @Brian add that as an answer, I'll accept it asap :)_

Comment: @Romen tcp::socket has no default constructor, so I can't declare it

Comment: Might be good to add [Why C++11 in-class initializer cannot use parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24836526/11082165) to the duplicate list as well.

Comment: I want to question the single-ness of server socket.. perhaps it's just interface to actual service, but then "socket" in name is a misnomer.. even is server operates with single socket at time, it have to be able to recreate it for normal operation, system configuration changes, error handling, etc. Socket is a file, a singleton controlling a file is..questionable. Typical singleton can't do that, they have a single life <.<