# lambda does not name a type in a class in C++

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

auto cmp = [](int a, int b) {
    return a > b;
};

class Test {
private:
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp);
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    Test test;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is below:
[image]

However, when I use the `priority_queue` in the main function, it can use the cmp.

Moreover, when I delete the 'cmp' in the 'pq'

```cpp
auto cmp = [](int a, int b) {
    return a > b;
};

class Test {
private:
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> pq;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    Test test;
    return 0;
}
```

the complier told me:

[image]

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

auto cmp = [](int a, int b) {
    return a > b;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   

    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp);
    pq.push(1);
    std::cout << pq.top() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I do not know why? I know lambda is a anonymous class, but why in a class it cannot use, in the main function it can use?

Comment: Note that with C++20 or higher, you do not need to repeat `cmp`. Having `decltype(cmp)` as the third template parameter is enough.

Comment: I delete the `cmp` in the 'pq`, the complier told me I use delete function

Comment: See dupe: [Why can't member initializers use parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836526/why-cant-member-initializers-use-parentheses)

Comment: The form `type name(arguments)` in a class definition is a member function declaration.

Comment: You need to enable C++20 or higher so that closure types have default constructors. See the `ClosureType::ClosureType()` section in [Lambda expressions on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the wonderful world of the Most Vexing Parse (well, not really, but close enough).

```
class Test {
private:
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> pq{cmp};
};
```

gcc 12 compiles this without any errors. Always use the uniform initialization syntax. It's your friend.

Comment: *"It's your friend."* Except when containers are involved, and there's no `=` sign. :c