# expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant

Tags: c++, c++11

Why `const std::string str="__$HOOK_FUNC_FOR_LUA_KEY@__";` is ok whereas
the compiler complains when compiling

`const std::string str("__$HOOK_FUNC_FOR_LUA_KEY@__");`?

**NOTE**: `str` is a member variable of a C++ class.

Demo code:

```
class Demo
{
private:
const std::string str("__$HOOK_FUNC_FOR_LUA_KEY@__");
}
```

Here are the the error messages:

```
test.hpp:253:51: error: expected identifier before string constant
     const std::string str("__$HOOK_FUNC_FOR_LUA_KEY@__");
                                                   ^
test.hpp:253:51: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant
```

It's obvious that there is ctor for `std::string(char*)`. So I am really confused.

Comment: It does work with curly brace initialization `str { "xxx" }`. I think that the issue is that the compiler has problem distinguishing whether `str` is a member or function when using round brackets `()`.

Comment: got a similar post here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052135/expected-identifier-before-string-constant

Comment: The [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) has striked again! The compiler sees that as a function declaration and emits a confusing message. Don't worry about it, most of us were caught...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: In fact, to avoid possible (most) vexing parse, that construct is simply forbidden. (inconsistency with initialization of regular variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have function-like inittialization inline in classes. You *must* use curly-braces `{}` or "assignment" like syntax with `=`.

It's a way to go around the problem of detecting if you're declaring a function or a variable.

And as you're dealing with `std::string` which has an `std::initializer_list` constructor (which will be used for curly-brace initialization) you can only use assignment-like syntax:

```
const std::string str = "__$HOOK_FUNC_FOR_LUA_KEY@__";
```

---

Of course, you can use a constructor initializer list as well:

```
Demo()
    : str("__$HOOK_FUNC_FOR_LUA_KEY@__")
{}
```

Comment: "It's a way to go around the problem of detecting if you're declaring a function or a variable?" You mean there is no other method to achieve this goal?

Comment: @John Unfortunately there's something in C++ called [*the most vexing parse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), where there's an ambiguity between variable definitions and function declarations. This was a way to not worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

For initializing of member variable you can use:

1. **Member initialize list**:

```cpp
A () : m_var ("something") {}
```

2. **Copy initialization**:

```cpp
struct A
{
  std::string m_var = "something";
};
```

3. **Value or list initialization**:

```cpp
struct A
{
  std::string m_var {"something"};
};
```

From CppReference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization